# CSS Styling Priority

Tags: html, css

I've just started learning course on basic HTML & CSS. I've been studying priority when it comes to CSS selectors today. Now, we have the following exercise that we were walking, I was wondering if someone can help me understand why 1,2 and 3 are Red, Red and Green when it comes to their text colors. As far As I understand, an ID takes preference over a class which in turn is a higher priority than just a regular element. So shouldnt 2 be green because we're setting .central to be green?

Thanks

```css
body {
  color: blue;
  background-color: yellow;
}
p {
  color: red;
}
.central, .item {
  color: green;
}
#item {
  background-color: cyan;
}
```

```html
<p>1</p>
<div class="central">
  <p>2</p>
  <ul>
    <li id="item">3</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: @VitorinoFernandes: `head` is closed when `body` starts.

Comment: @VitorinoFernandes: And about style priority. Not exactly, if the stronger selector is at the bottom, it's used. The rule you mentioned is applied only when there are selectors of the same strength.

Comment: Do they really teach you to use such markup? Don't set expectations too high then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the CSS model, every element has all properties defined in CSS specifications, such as the `color` property. In your example, the element `<p>2</p>` matches only one CSS rule, namely the one that sets the `color` property to `red` for `p` element. Thus, regarding the color of “2”, there is priority issue to be resolved.

Whatever values are set on outer elements cannot possibly affect the `color` property here.

Answer (score 1):

First You correct Your Markup.

The style Priority is given From top to bottom. There is rule for id or class selectors.

Order of precedence of CSS Style Rules are:

> 1 User defined style
>
> 2 Embedded or inline style sheet
>
> 3 Internal style sheet
>
> 4 External style sheet
>
> 5 Browser default style

Comment: Not exactly: internal stylesheet and external one are the same priority, the more specific rule is applied, or, when rules has the same strength, the last one and it dones't matter if it's in interal or external stylesheet.

Comment: Not an answer to the question asked.

Answer (score 0):

The second one is and should be red, it works correctly.

Everything in the `.central` is green, but paragraphs are red.I created you a fiddle.

```
<div class="central">
    green outside the &lt;p>
    <p>red paragraph</p>
</div>    

<style>
    p {color: red;} 
    .central {color: green;}
</style>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/st393nmz/

Of course, if you add a rule for paragraphs inside `.central`, this rule will be applied.

```
<style>
    .central p {color: blue} /* paragraph above will be blue, not red */
</style>
```

Comment: That's interesting, The way I understood priority was that the class would override the element, essentially how it's explained here: http://monc.se/kitchen/38/cascading-order-and-inheritance-in-css

Comment: Sure, the table there (with a/b/c and point for element/class/id) is correct and I tried to find that too :-) `.central` has higher priority than `p`, but `p` is in the above layer. Example, which can help you to understand it more: http://jsfiddle.net/st393nmz/

Comment: Hmm, Somehow this just seems contradictory to me when I try to study specificity in CSS. For example, looking at this: http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/27/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/ 
I know that a HTML selector is less specific than a class selector but yet in our case, the HTML selector (p{}) takes precedence over the class selector (.central)

Comment: @DavidW: `.central` and `p` are in different layers in your example. Precendence for class selector is obvious from my code in comment above, `.central` is more than `p`. But because of the paragraph has this class too (`p.central` is more than just `p`)

Comment: @DavidW: thing which can help you is to change `color` to `background`. http://jsfiddle.net/st393nmz/1/ - div is green, but inner paragraph is red, with background it's more obvious. With color it's work the same way.

Answer (score 0):

You set green color for your div tag contents only. So it doesn't affect your paragraph tag contents because you mentioned color red for the paragraph.And also note your background color yellow for body doesn't affect because start of your style tag check out the below Markup:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body> 
    <p>1</p>
    <div class="central"><p class="central">2</p>
    <ul>
    <li id="item" >3</li>
    </ul>
    </div>
    </body>
 <style>
    body {
    color: blue;
    background-color:yellow;
    }
    p {
    color: red;
    } 
     .central,.item{
    color: green;
    }
    #item {
    background-color: cyan;
    }
    </style>
```

Comment: background will be yellow, `head` part is closed correctly when `body` starts. `head` and `body` (and some more elements) has *optional* start and end tag too.